# keep zero left in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, zero

I'm creating a VBA application, when I enter a number I want to get the same but in packages (ex: I enter 12000244 I'll got 1200 0244 ) but I have a problem that I lost the left zero ( I got 1200 244 ). so if any body have a solution please.

this is my code :

```
Dim renvoie As String
renvoie = ""
For i = taille - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If i <> 0 Then
        renvoie = renvoie + CStr(tableau(i)) + " "
    Else
        renvoie = renvoie + Left(attention, 5 - Len(tableau(i))) + CStr(tableau(i)) + " "
        MsgBox tableau(i)
    End If
    taille = taille - 1
Next i
text_resultat.Caption = CStr(renvoie)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

use [Format()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) function:

```
format("12000244", "0000 0000") ' returns string "1200 0244"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as i found that you can use the format function with this syntax Format(Expression, [Format], [FirstDayOfWeek], [FirstWeekOfYear]) so its working for a calendar, so i tried it it didn't works.

Comment: I don’t get you. If you run my code in Immediate Window with the input string as per your question example you get desired output. If you have different input string pattern you’d better enhance your question

Answer (score 0):

That `For Next` loop looks a little odd, especially when you modify `taille` within the loop. It's also hard to see what all of your variables are, as the declarations aren't given in your code.

If you want to add a space into text of a known length and at a known point, then the code is basically just this:

```
Dim sampleNumAsStr As String, result As String
Dim splitPoint As Long

sampleNumAsStr = "12000244"
splitPoint = 4

result = Left(sampleNumAsStr, splitPoint) & " " & _
         Right(sampleNumAsStr, Len(sampleNumAsStr) - splitPoint)
```